# Apex Push a list of ids in a Pagereference parameter

Tags: url, controller, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am trying to push a list of Ids to a URL parameter using a string, when the VF Page load, this is how it looks like - I get a bunch of %27%2C%27:

"/00O1f000000W6c5?pv0=%27a1D1f000000GC8tEAG%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE1AEAW%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE3QEAW%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE3VEAW%27&pv1=%27a1D1f000000GC8tEAG%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE1AEAW%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE3QEAW%27%2C%27a1D1f000000GE3VEAW%27"

while my expectation is to have it posted like this

"/00O1f000000W6c5?pv0=('a1D1f000000GC8tEAG','a1D1f000000GE1AEAW','a1D1f000000GE3QEAW',.......)

below my controller and code

```
public with sharing class AccountLoanCollateralControllerTESTSAAD {

public Id AccountId { get; set; }
public Account Acc { get; set; }
list<ID> listcoll = new list<ID>();
list<string>liststring=new list<string>();
string idString;
string url;


public AccountLoanCollateralController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {





Acc= (Account) controller.getRecord();
list<LLC_BI__Account_Collateral__c> AccColl=[select LLC_BI__Collateral__c from LLC_BI__Account_Collateral__c where LLC_BI__Account__c =:Acc.Id and LLC_BI__Collateral__r.Type1__c like '%agreement%'];

for(LLC_BI__Account_Collateral__c ac: AccColl)
{

listcoll.add(Ac.LLC_BI__Collateral__c);
liststring.add('\''+string.valueof(Ac.LLC_BI__Collateral__c)+'\'');

}

idString = string.join(liststring,',');
url=  string.valueof(idString);


}


public PageReference Run() {

        //build your code logic here
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/00O1f000000W6c5?pv0=' + url + '&pv1='+url);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
       return pageRef;

       }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected functionality. Browsers automatically encode urls and replace characters with their [corresponding code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

You need to [decode the url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlDecode) in the page that receives the parameters

If this is a standard salesforce page that you cannot control then what you are doing is essentially URL hacking and are learning the repercussions of doing so.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it - what I am trying to do is pushing a list of ids in a comma separated pattern into the pv0 filter of a dyanamic report, because right now the report class does not support Joined reports programming...

Answer (score 0):

Try to send them without "()" and without apostrophes, you overcomplicated it. Reports don't need same syntax than say SOQL.

Just the comma-separated IDs.

In my org: `/00O0g000005Z3I7?pv0=0017000000Lg8Wa,0017000000Lg8Wg,0017000000Lg8WX&isdtp=vw` gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks, here is what I did - I created a text field on the Account object called Report_Collateral__c, and a URL link on the Account object with this detail:
/00O1f000000W6hj?pv0={!Account.Report_Collateral__c}&pv1={!Account.Report_Collateral__c}, on an Account record I setup this field with: a1D1f000000GC8t,a1D1f000000GE1A when the end user clicks on that link the URL end up looking like this in the browser: dev.cs99.my.salesforce.com/00O1f000000W6hj?pv0=a1D1f000000GC8t%2Ca1D1f000000GE1A&pv1=a1D1f000000GC8t%2Ca1D1f000000GE1A The %2C endup corrupting the Report filter

Comment: Looks like "," gets unneccessarily encoded. That URL field is normal editable field or a formula? Or is it a real link like in "buttons, links and actions" menu? You might want to experiment a bit with formulas, read a bit about URLFOR, HYPERLINK... Worst case see if you can brute force it with `SUBSTITUTE(myFinalLink, "%2C", ",")`. And if it's a real link - yeah, see if you'll get better results with a formula field. Might give you bit more control

Comment: I'm bit confused now, you have problem with a link/formula field? Or with apex code & pagereferences? Or are you in "just do what it takes to display the report" situation, doesn't matter how?

Comment: I was trying to show that the comma separation is getting URL encoded which prevents the report filter to take action. Overall here are the expectations: the ids that I have after the pv0 and pv1 are getting retrieved from a soql query at the VF Page controller level, those are coming as a list that I seperate using comma: string.join(liststring,','); the VF Page calls the run method which holds the pagereference to the report - I don`t think that the option of using a link on the account object will work, that was solely for demonstration

Comment: removing the quotes from the controller liststring.add('\''+string.valueof(Ac.LLC_BI__Collateral__c)+'\''); end up with the same result than the link option, URL encoding of the comma symbol